# Reporting in MVC using an IReportRepository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on an existing system and need to add a report via a stored procedure.
I just want to sort out some errors first.

In IReportingRepository.cs I have:

```
 public interface IReportingRepository
 {
     IEnumerable<LastSundayDate<DateTime>> GetTradeMeKPISearches();
 }
```

the first error is on the line above the LastSundayDate> part and says:
The non-generic type 'TradeUK.Entities.Reporting.LastSundayDate' cannot be used with type arguments

I have a class LastSundayDate.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TradeUK.Entities.Reporting
{
    public class LastSundayDate
    {
       public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In ReportingServies.cs I have:

```
public IEnumerable<LastSundayDate> GetTradeUKKPISearches()
{
  return ReportingRepository.GetTradeUKKPISearches();
}
```

and then in ReportingRepository.cs I have:

```
 public IEnumerable<LastSundayDate<DateTime>> GetTradeMeKPISearches()
{
  try
  {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(TradeUKModelContainer.CONNECTIONSTRING))
    {
      conn.Open();

      using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
      {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "[Reporting].[GetTradeMEKPISearches]";

        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          da.Fill(dt);

          List<LastSundayDate<DateTime>> results = new List<LastSundayDate<DateTime>>();

          foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
          {
            string title = dr["Title"].ToString();
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Total"]);

            results.Add(new LastSundayDate<>());
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception("ReportingRepository GetTradeUKKPISearches: Error", ex);
  }
}
```

why can i not have the type as DateTime?
thanks

Comment: It is very bad title for question, because IReportingRepository is your private interface and all users don't understand what is this question about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class

```
public class LastSundayDate
{
   public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

is not generic, so you cannot use it as `LastSundayDate<DateTime>`.

Why don't you write

```
public interface IReportingRepository
{
    IEnumerable<LastSundayDate> GetTradeMeKPISearches();
}
```